# how to add support to download a file on a php page?

Tags: php, download

We want to support a feature on our php page such that when user clicks on a button on the page, we  will automatically generate some data into a file and download the file to the client side. A lot of websites has such feature today (for example, download chrome image to install on client machine), how to achieve that in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is a bit vague ("generate some data") but it's going to be something like this.  I'm ass-u-ming your data comes from a SQL query:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=YOUR_EXPORT.txt");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

$your_query = mysql_query( "select * from bla bla bla ... ");
while( $codes = mysql_fetch_array( $your_query ) ) {
    $row = array();
    $row[] = some data ... 
    fputs($fp, $row);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

On your php page with the button, have the button trigger to open a file you are going to write to and send to the browser for download (for example a .CSV file):

```
            <html>
            <head>
               <!-- Using jquery -->
               <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
               <script>
                   $("#download_file").click(function(){ 
                        window.open("generate_a_csv_file.php","_blank");
                   });
               </script>
            </head>

            <body>
                <input type="button" value="Download CSV File">
            </body>
            </html>
```

Then create another php file that will generate the contents, using a header to tell the browser to send the contents as a file (in this example a file named "example_file.csv" will generated for download):

```
    <?php

    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=example_file.csv');
    header('Content-type: application/force-download');

    echo "line1,abc,123"."\r\n";
    echo "line2,xyz,456"."\r\n";  

    ?>
```

NOTE: Make sure you don't output anything above the "header" lines. The header must be outputted before anything else is.

Comment: thanks! but how would #download_file get triggered? I mean I don't see  the connection between the button and the script...